# JS Link to convert the webparts on the page to accordian

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jslink

On a webpart page we have around 4 webparts to start with. Each webpart has some `data: image, text, video.` We want this information to be displayed in an Accordian format. I.E each webpart title should server as an accordian tab and the content as data that show/hide on click on accordian tab.How to convert the webparts on the page into accordian using jS Link?

Comment: A little more information about what you are trying to do would be helpful to avoid the risk of this question being voted to be closed

Answer (score 1):

A good sample is available on https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-ccdb2a0e

I am copying the code for easy reference

```
// List View – Accordion Sample 
// Muawiyah Shannak , @MuShannak 

(function () { 

    // jQuery library is required in this sample 
    // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var accordionContext = {}; 
    accordionContext.Templates = {}; 

    // Be careful when add the header for the template, because it's will break the default list view render 
    accordionContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='accordion'>"; 
    accordionContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>"; 

    // Add OnPostRender event handler to add accordion click events and style 
    accordionContext.OnPostRender = accordionOnPostRender; 

    // This line of code tell TemplateManager that we want to change all HTML for item row render 
    accordionContext.Templates.Item = accordionTemplate; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(accordionContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function accordionTemplate(ctx) { 
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"]; 
    var description = ctx.CurrentItem["Description"]; 

    // Return whole item html 
    return "<h2>" + title + "</h2><p>" + description + "</p><br/>"; 
} 

function accordionOnPostRender() { 

    // Register event to collapse and uncollapse when click on accordion header 
    $('.accordion h2').click(function () { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
    }).next().hide(); 

    $('.accordion h2').css('cursor', 'pointer'); 
}
```

**Deployment steps:**

1. Create a Custom List
2. Add a new column to the list:

   ```
   - Name: Description
   - Type: Multiple lines of text
   ```
3. Edit the Default New Form
4. Go to List view web-part properties and add the JSLink file (~sitecollection/Style Library/JSLink-Samples/Accordion.js) to JS link property under the Miscellaneous Tab.
5. Click Apply button then Stop page editing